# Is there a way to add just a few lines to the CSS code to make this menu become 47 px height uniformly?

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu, alignment

I have just added this pre-made css menu to my site and I have kinda played around with resizing it. I have used "height: 47px; and could only adjust the actual height of the menu, and the rest such as text seems to be harder to aligh and keep it nice and tidy.

Now.......I thought it was going to be easier to set the whole menu to 47 px uniformly.

Here is the actual menu: http://jsbin.com/xiwayugu/2/

I am wondering what exactly I should adjust to 47 px (apart from the #cssmenu and #cssmenu > ul that I have already adjusted) to keep this menu nice and tidy?

Then again...one of the reasons I am asking this question is because I'd like to know for future references what parts to adjust (and are responsible) for changing the height and keeping a menu uniformly at a specific pixel height.

Comment: 'nice and tidy' are not enough information to understand what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Change the height of the <li>'s to 100%, change the height of the <a>'s to 100%, and set margin to 0px's. Change the span's height to 100%. set the line-height of the span to 47px. and use vertical-align: middle; Also set the padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;

Answer (score 0):

Line-height could be one way to fix thoses heights: **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/xiwayugu/5/edit)**

For instance, if you tune the line-height to the links :

```
#cssmenu a {
  line-height: 33px;
}
```

You gave already an `height` to other elements , so `<a>` is the only to tune here in this case.

**Notice**, that styling `<a>` line-height, you do need to set any height on parents. they will expand in order to fit final height of `<a>` [jsbin.com/xiwayugu/6/edit](http://jsbin.com/xiwayugu/6/edit)